# OpenXML append rows to an existing table in Word

Tags: c#, openxml, word-table

I want to append rows to an existing table which has the header row only. I use OpenXML but I cannot open Word document due to error 0x80004005.
Here is the source I think is OK but...:

```
public static byte[] WordDocument(List<List<string>> data)
{
  using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
  {
    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(templatePath);
    mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true))
    {
      Table table = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().First();
      foreach (var line in data)
      {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        foreach (var column in line)
        {
          TableCell tc = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(column))));
          tr.Append(tc);
        }
        table.Append(new TableRow());
      }
    }
    return mem.ToArray();
  }
}
```

document.xml:
[PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/LTvDuUyU)

Comment: Could you attach your table in word file ? I would like and share you answer

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering me. Of course, I create it. A moment, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewind the stream after writing to it. Out of interest, why use a stream anyway, rather than just loading from the document directly?

Shouldn't that be `table.Append(tr);` instead of `table.Append(new TableRow());`?

Comment: Oh, yes. You are right! I did not notice it. Many thanx. :)